# Is there a way to use VBA to change the language in VBA generated worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I was assigned a project at work to develop a Macro that would automatically take financial data from an Excel table and generate credit notes and invoices for customers. I have the Macro developed already it is working the way it should, but the issue I am running into is with the language that is used for each invoice.

When generating credit notes, the Macro is taking the the invoices month of issue from the financial data table and displaying then as them as the months where credit was issued to the customer. i.e., a customer is requesting a partial refund on transactions from a period of time (say Feb.2019 - Apr. 2019) it will be displayed as:

```
February 2019 (02-19)     -20.20
March 2019 (03-19)        -32.03
April 2019 (04-19)        -24.21
```

The problem is that my primary working language is English, but my company works in several European marketplaces and the invoices and credit notes have to be displayed in the language of the market where the customer is located.

So if an Italian customer requests an invoice, the months displayed must be listed as

```
Febbraio 2019 (02-19)     -20.20
Marzo 2019 (03-19)        -32.03
Aprile 2019 (04-19)       -24.21
```

However, when running the Macro it still displays the issuing months in English when it should be displayed in the language of the market. The entirety of all invoices and credit notes created with this Macro are generated in the correct language, but since the Macro is taking the issuing months from the data table it automatically displays them in English.

Is the any way to ensure that it displays the issuing months in the required language?

I already know that the language settings can be changed for the entire workbook, but I still run into the same problem as I would have to manually change the issuing language each time I run the Macro to ensure the issuing month is correct?

Comment: Welcome to SO. As far as I know, Excel updates/adapt some datas into country settings of wherever the file is opened. I work with some easy files with dates with format `mmmm-yyyy` and I see that info in spanish (Enero 2019), but people from other countries see that info in english (January 2019). So I guess your data saying `February 2019 (02-19)` is a string, and not a date type, and Excel in that case won't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To format a date in another regional setting you need to change the number format of the date for the desired range of cells. Eg. format the cell pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to get the following dialog, and choose the regional setting (*"Gebietsschema"*) for the country you desire.

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Change the regional setting for the date (sorry for the German screenshot).</sup>*

Alternatively use the [Range.NumberFormat property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat) to format the cell with VBA:

```
.NumberFormat = "[$-it-IT]d mmmm yyyy;@"
```

Note that these both work if your dates are **real date values** but don't work if your dates are text. If they are text you need to change them into real dates.